# List directories that contain two consecutive vowels in name. Linux terminal command

Tags: regex, linux, grep, ls

The question is:
Write a command to print the number of directories in /home that contain two consecutive vowels (lowercase).

I tried:

```
ls /home/*[aeiou][aeiou]*
```

however this is obvious on why it doesn't work.

I tried:

```
ls /home | grep *[aeiou][aeiou]*
```

and I get nothing. I know once I figure out how to isolate the directories with the two consecutive vowels I need to pipe that into the wc command. Or if I use grep to do it I can just use -c. I have also tried find but that was no good.

Comment: `ls -d *[aeiou][aeiou]*/` is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` does regex-matching, not glob matching.

```
ls -d */ | grep '[aeiou]\{2\}'
```

When you tried nearly the same thing, you did not quote the regular expression.  That's why it didn't work for you: Shell treated the regexp as a file glob, expanding it to the list of matching files (if any), rather than passing the regexp to grep.  Quoting the regexp prevents the shell from treating it as a glob and expanding it.

Thanks @harpo for how to filter for directories.

Comment: Um, no, that {2,2} is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: @tchrist OK, what is it doing?  I seem to get the results I expect when I test it.

Comment: There is no difference between `{2}` and `{2,2}`, except to require more typing and also risk confusing people with the bulky synonym that changes nothing.  Furthermore, it doesn’t preclude *more* than two, so for example `beauty`.  Many people are surprised by this, thinking their `{2,2}` would not match that, but of course it does.  Plus I don’t really understand why \y\o\u \w\o\u\l\d \w\a\n\t to use `grep` with all its exxxtra backslllashes over `egrep` with its cleaner syntax.  Still, you don’t really need either.

Answer (score 4):

Refining @sverre's answer,

```
ls -d */ | grep '[aeiou]\{2,2\}'
```

you don't need the `.*` before and after — it will find matches within by default.

The `-d` option with `*/` will print only directory names.

Comment: I used a combination of yours and @sverre's answer. Thanks!

Comment: Again, {2,2} is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: @tchrist, can you explain?  I tested in cygwin, and I think it was doing what I think it was.

Answer (score 4):

All you need is:

```
 ls -d *[aeiou][aeiou]*/
```

Because the trailing slash will restrict the glob to directories.

It becomes dicier if you want it to be case insensitive, or be recursive, or to include directories whose names start with dot, or if you want to include `y` when it’s a vowel but not a consonant, or you need to account for possible diacritics on your vowels, &c&c&c.

Answer (score 2):

You use `find` to restrict the search to directories. Since `find` is recursive, you have to set lower and upper bounds of the filesystem objects traversed. Then you print a character per entry, and count them up.

```
find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*[aeiou][aeiou]*' -printf '*' | wc -c
```

Comment: Note that -mindepth, -maxdepth, and -printf are GNU find extensions, so this is not a fully portable solution.  But it does filter out non-directories, and it does work even if there are newlines in the directory names, unlike "ls | grep '[aeiou][aeiou]'"

Comment: BSD find has `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth`, but not `-printf`. POSIX find has none of the three.

Answer (score 2):

`ls /home/*[aeiou][aeiou]*` is going to find the directories you want, but then list comments.

`ls -d /home/*[aeiou][aeiou]*` will list the directory names, not their contents.

`ls -d /home/*[aeiou][aeiou]* | wc -l` will count the number of matching entries.

As others have pointed out, adding a `/` onto the end will ensure that you see only directories and not ordinary files that have two vowels.

Comment: Character ranges are valid in globs.

Comment: Why, so they are. How did I not know that?